# Fire GTM tag only if on homepage of the site

Tags: google-tag-manager

The homepage can also have extra GET params (e.g. utm tags and similar marketing variables). How can I make it work? Simple "end with http://example.com or http://example.com/" doesn't work cause the url might be http://example.com/?utm_campaign=text&...

Thanks!

Comment: There is a predefined page path variable that does not contain domain or query string (i.e. the page path for  "http://example.com/?utm_campaign=text&..." would simply be "/").

Answer (score 23):

The best practice is always install the GTM along you domain and execute it whenever you need.
To launch a tag only in the home you need to use the following trigger. Add this on you custom HTML tag, take care of the equals.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, spent some time trying to figure it out, even put Fire On: Page URL equals {full url of my site}, but Kemen's solution works perfectly.

Comment: This won't work if you have any query parameters though, right? eg domain.com?foo=bar won't match this condition - I think you'd need to use regex, like @nocabt's suggestion

Comment: @hobailey pagepath parameters doest include the query parameters so is not necesary to add regex. You're using page URL or Document Regex.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old thread; but I found it after I solved this myself. I created a trigger for `Page Path` `matches RegEx` and used:

`^\/(\?(.*))?$`

What that does is matches for ONLY the hostname with no path (www.domain.com/) OR matches if a `?` follows the `/`.

Might be another way to do this. Completed trigger:

[image: Completed Trigger for matching homepage]

Comment: Thanks, this properly handled the use case with additional tracking parameters and should be ranked higher.

Answer (score 3):

I've achieved the same using Page Path matches RegEx

```
^\/$|^\/\?
```

This means: match a string that begins (^) and ends ($) with / OR (|) that begins with /?

\ precedes special characters to denote that they should be treated as text and are not part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only needed to fire the GTM tag in two paths `/` and `/shop`, so the following rule worked for me: `Page Path matches RegEx ^\/$|^\/shop$` I hope you can find it useful too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I know this is an old thread; but I found it after I solved this myself. I created a trigger for Page Path matches RegEx and used:
>
> ^/(?(.*))?$
> What that does is matches for ONLY the hostname with no path ([www.domain.com/](http://www.domain.com/)) OR matches if a ? follows the /.

--->The GTM page path won't include parameter(the ?xxxx of [www.domain.com?xxxxx](http://www.domain.com?xxxxx))
So I guess there is no need for setting up the ?xxx part condition. Only the "/" part of the homepage should be find.